# PHP - Variable assignment in function call

Tags: php

I have the following code where I try to assign a value to a variable and then evaluate if it's empty:

```
if(!empty($user = User::find($id))){
   // do some operations on the $user
}
```

But I'm getting an error... Does the PHP compiler allows this in any way?

PS. I'm using PHP 5.3

Comment: If you have `$user` previously in the context then put `==` instead of `=` otherwise the return value of `User::find` is not suitable for `empty`.

Comment: @MahanGM I believe he's assigning a value rather than comparing it

Comment: php is an interpreted language.  what php compiler are you using, hiphop?  can you provide some additional context?  also, I think you should reconsider checking for !empty on the find method you are calling with an injected value.  If you were unit testing this it would be a mess.  break out your functionality into reuseable units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if a function cant find something, ie a User, then it would return `false` anyway - so this is what I normally do:

```
if($user = User::find($id))
   // do some operations on the $user
}
else
{
   // no user found 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does the PHP compiler allows this in any way?

Check out [manual page about empty](http://php.net/empty):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error.

In your code you have assignment operation instead of plain variable.